# XSL value-of bold text

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

I have the following block

```
 <xsl:template match="body/data">
     <fo:block font-size="10pt" border-collapse="separate" border-separation="5pt">
          <xsl:value-of select="reason" />
          <xsl:value-of select="description" />
        </fo:block>
 </xsl:template>
```

I want to make the "reason" bold and "description" not bold and I want them to be on 1 line without any space between them. For example if reason is "Banned:" and description is "Hacking" I want to display:

**BANNED:** Hacking

how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Use `font-weight` (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#font-weight) to specify a bold font.

```
 <xsl:template match="body/data">
     <fo:block font-size="10pt">
          <fo:inline font-weight="bold">
            <xsl:value-of select="reason" />
          </fo:inline>
          <xsl:text>: </xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of select="description" />
        </fo:block>
 </xsl:template>
```

---

Also, `border-collapse` and `border-separation` only apply to `fo:table`.